# ASP.NET MVC как заменить повторяющиеся слеши в URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

У меня есть пару страниц в проекте по примеру localhost:port/price или localhost:/buy.
Иногда слеш заедает(да глупо, но бывает), а я привык прописывать URL ручками (извините) и получается localhost:port////price....

Можно ли как то отключить/заменить/убрать эти повторяющиеся слеши на всего лишь один?

Comment: попробуйте смотреть на URL когда его вбиваете и исправлять, когда он неверный. Просто ваш вопрос выглядит так, будто вы сами себе проблемы создаете.

Comment: Прописывать что бы то ни было руками, если это можно сделать не руками -- сильнейшей степени моветон.